# Jenkins pass browser URL as parameter of a Maven Selenium Java test

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I'm looking for a solution to pass a variable ( an URL in my case ) in parameter in Jenkins when the jobs is built

I want to do this, because i have to execute the same test in various website. Pass the URL as parameter will be a good way to don't have to copy/paste 10 times the same maven project just to specifiy an URL.

For my test I use selenium and everything is developped in Java.

Do you have some ideas ? I see some post with solutions, but nothing works for me.

Thanks for help !

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using the [Matrix Project plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Matrix+Project+Plugin).

Create a multi-configuration job and add an user defined axis like below:

[image]

Next, use this axis in your build step:

[image]

Jenkins will launch 3 jobs to test the 3 different values:

[image]
[image]

Output for the 3 jobs:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Does it help? :)

Comment: Of course it helps ! Can this values be send or captured by my java class ?

Comment: If your java class can read the environment variables, you can try to read the BROWER_URL variable. If my solution help, don't forget to vote for it and mark as the good answer :)

Comment: Ok I will try this,and will report you the issue